# Getting a int value from a string value of a column in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How to extract only a integer value from a string of values consisting integers, braces, characters.
Ex:- I have an issue with this -> 946.73 [1](June 2020). I want to remove [1](June 2020) from that string or i want to extract 946.73 from that string.
i have used filter method
mobile is dataframe and Total subscribers is column and this column consists of values like 946.73 [1](June 2020).
so i need to get only the integer value from that column values.
i tried this method.

mobile['Total Subscribers']= int(filter(str.isdigit, mobile['Total Subscribers']))

```
url="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mobile_network_operators"
mobile=pd.read_html(url,match="Company")
mobile=mobile[0]
mobile=mobile.set_index('Rank').rename(columns={'Totalsubscriptions(in 
millions)':'Total Subscribers','Ownership(100% ownership unless stated 
otherwise)':'Ownership'})
mobile['Total Subscribers']=mobile['Total Subscribers'].apply(lambda x: 
re.search(r'\d+', x).group())
mobile['Total Subscribers']
for i in mobile['Total Subscribers']:
    a=re.sub("[^\d\.]", "", i)
    mobile['Total Subscribers']=a
    return mobile['Total Subscribers']
```

This is my code. please solve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try a regex replacement which will target the square bracket and parenthesis and its contents.

`\[.*\]\(.*\)`

i.e

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'data' : ['946.73 [1](June 2020)']})

print(df)

                    data
0  946.73 [1](June 2020)

 df['data'].replace(r'\[.*\]\(.*\)','',regex=True)

0    946.73
Name: data, dtype: object
```

edit - changed requirement.

```
mobile['Total Subscribers'].str.extract(r'(\d+.\d+)')[0]


Rank
1.0     946.73
2.0     420.00
3.0     398.30
4.0     343.47
5.0     309.52
6.0     279.80
7.0     277.50
8.0     261.46
9.0     261.34
10.0    256.20
11.0    207.96
12.0    204.60
13.0    182.42
14.0    185.50
15.0    171.41
16.0    162.57
17.0    146.10
18.0    145.84
19.0    123.22
20.0    119.87
21.0    118.32
22.0     110.0
23.0     98.49
24.0     89.32
25.0     86.40
26.0     79.67
27.0     75.10
28.0     73.08
29.0      54.5
30.0     52.42
NaN        NaN
```

Comment: Guys i have edited my question with my source code. Please look at that

Comment: @Tirumaleshn this works for me - `mobile['Total Subscribers'].str.extract(r'(\d+.\d+)')[0]`

Comment: Thank you so much my friend! @Manakin

Answer (score 0):

Your questions is bit confusing for me if you say you need all numeric values from a string then your regex or any other is.digit function with return the 1 and 2020 as well.
Example if I write a regex which will keep all numeric values and handling float as well then the output result would be something like :

```
    import re
a=re.sub("[^\d\.]", "", "946.73 [1](June 2020)")
```

***Output : 946.7312020***

Or what you can do is convert the whole thing to a dataframe and try to acknowledge all the parenthesis and replace them as well.
You will have to use .replace function for that please do read documentation for more clarity.

I guess this should work for you

```
.replace(r'\[.*\]\(.*\)','',regex=True)
```

you can set regex=False if you need to use it as a switch .

```
.replace(r'\[.*\]\(.*\)','',regex=False)
```

Comment: Yes, but i have explained in my question with an example. I want to get 946.63 from 946.73 [1](June 2020). And the value of a respective r,c should be 946.63

Comment: url="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mobile_network_operators"
mobile=pd.read_html(url,match="Company")
mobile=mobile[0]
mobile=mobile.set_index('Rank').rename(columns={'Totalsubscriptions(in millions)':'Total Subscribers','Ownership(100% ownership unless stated otherwise)':'Ownership'})
mobile['Total Subscribers']=mobile['Total Subscribers'].apply(lambda x: re.search(r'\d+', x).group())
mobile['Total Subscribers']
for i in mobile['Total Subscribers']:
    a=re.sub("[^\d\.]", "", i)
    mobile['Total Subscribers']=a
    return mobile['Total Subscribers'This is my code.pls solve

Answer (score 0):

If your value to be extracted is always a floating point you could use a simple [regular expression](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) which matches only this:

```
import re
text="946.73 [1](June 2020)"
matches = re.findall("\d+\.\d+", text)

if len(matches) == 1:    
   print(matches[0])
else:
   raise ValueError
```